# Symfony 4. Parameters for custom service

Tags: symfony4

I've created a service MailService. Where is the right place for the service configuration? Is it the file services.yml? If I write

```
App\Service\MailService:
      someparam: somevalue
```

I get the error message 
The configuration key `someparam` is unsupported for definition `App\Service\MailService`.
How to configure the service properly? How to read the params within my service?

```
class MailService
{
    public function __construct()
    {
    }

}
```

Comment: Please insert MailService source code to your question

Comment: I have inserted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass some data by constructor parameters and **correct service configuration**:

**Service class:**

```
class MailService
{
    private $adminEmail;

    private $adminName;

    public function __construct($adminEmail, $adminName)
    {
        $this->adminEmail = $adminEmail;
        $this->adminName = $adminName;
    }

}
```

**Services configuration:**

```
App\Service\MailService:
    arguments:
        $adminEmail: 'manager@example.com'
        $adminName: 'Admin Name'
```

Read more about [Dependency Injection and autowiring in Symfony 4 projects](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection.html)

---

[image]

Comment: Thank you!
I've read, I can do so:
parameters:
  adminEmail: someValue


App\Service\MailService:
arguments: ['%adminEmail%']

For what do I need the section in parameters? What is the advantage?

Comment: All about parameters in Symfony you can read in documentation: https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/configuration.html#constants-vs-configuration-options

You can use parameters to define configuration options which can change. For example: `default language` or `path to your private JWT key`... Look above at the picture I added